# Сериализация и десериализация csv в python

Tags: python, csv

после сериализации в файле сохраняется только последняя строчка изначальной таблицы

```
1;3;4
q;w;e 
r;e;w
```

```
import csv
import pickle

with open ("Proba_fail.csv", newline = '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader (csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        pickle.dump((row['1'], row['3'], row['4']), open("BabyFile.txt", 'ab+'))


c=pickle.load(open("BabyFile.txt", 'rb'))
print (c)
```

на выводе только
`('r', 'e', 'w')`

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: все значения таблицы:
q w e 
r e w